# Can't find function in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I am working on a classical asp project (supporting).So i am fixing bugs in the existing site.The visual studio is not able to find a vb function, for example

```
//aPerfInfo is a array value

OFunc.GetNameAndTitle(cstr(aPerfInfo(7,0));
```

In the above code i need to know where is GetNameAndTitle had written and what is OFunc or where it resides.(It is very hard to find a function using find bar of vs2010)

my question is whether the vs2010 can support "Go to definition functionality or not", Or is there any other way (like plug in) to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your VS2010 FIND dialog....

Enter your search criteria... 
Like maybe **GetNameAndTitle**
 and then in the DROPDOWN at the bottom make sure its sets to SEARCH ENTIRE SOLUTION...

[image]